# The number of certain subgroup of an elementary abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G \cong \Bbb{Z}_q \times \Bbb{Z}_q \times \Bbb{Z}_q \times \Bbb{Z}_q$ be an elementary abelian group. I want to know my following calculation  is correct?

The number of subgroups of $G$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_q \times \Bbb{Z}_q$ is equal to $\frac{(q^4-1)(q^4-q)}{(q^2-1)(q^2-q)}$

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: It would improve your Question to give your reasoning, whether heuristic or rigorous, for the proposed count of subgroups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb{Z}_q)^n$ then it can be regarded as a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $\Bbb{Z}_q$, and the subgroups are just the subspaces.
The number of linearly independent lists of length $m$ is

$(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\dotsb(q^n-q^{m-1})$

For any subspace $V$ of dimension $m$, the number of bases is

$(q^m-1)(q^m-q)\dotsb(q^m-q^{m-1})$

It follows that the number of subspaces of dimension $m$ is
 $ \frac{(q^n-1)\dotsb(q^n-q^{m-1})}{(q^m-1)\dotsb(q^m-q^{m-1})} 
       $